# Continuous Function of a Riemann Integrable Function is Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

I'd like to prove the following, which I'm reasonably sure is true:

**Proposition.** If $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and nondecreasing, then $g \circ f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable.

My idea is to use the Darboux definition of the integral: Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and let $h_1 \leq f \leq h_2$ be piecewise constant functions such that $\int_a^b h_2(x)\,dx - \int_a^b h_1(x)\,dx \leq \epsilon$. Then $g\circ h_1 \leq g \circ f \leq g \circ h_2$, where the outer functions are Riemann integrable (since they're piecewise continuous). The problem is bounding $\int_a^b g \circ h_2(x)\,dx - \int_a^b g \circ h_1(x)\,dx$ by a suitable function of $\epsilon$, since it's hard to tell how $g$ will distort the regions under these curves. How should I proceed? (I'd like to prove this straight from the definition of Darboux integrability, rather than from the fact that Riemann integrability is equivalent to continuity a.e.)

Comment: $f$ is bounded and continuous almost everywhere hence so is $g\circ f.$

Comment: It is not true that $h_1 \leq f \leq h_2$ implies $g\circ h_1 \leq g \circ f \leq g \circ h_2$ (it would be true if $g$ were assumed to be non decreasing)

Comment: @StratosFair good catch, just added this condition to the hypothesis.

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm aware of the equivalence between Riemann integrability and continuity a.e., but I'd like to prove this straight from the definition. (Updated the post to reflect this)

Comment: [Related 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207876) and [Related 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4625946). Could the 2nd one be considered as a duplicate?

Comment: See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2439694/148510) for the general proof with Darboux sums where $f$ is Riemann integrable and $g$ is continuous.  There is no requirement that $g$ be nondecreasing.